# Recovering eigenvector Eigen decomposition

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

is anyone familiar with the recovery process of an eigenvector using the formula iteration with eigen decomposition?
Its said if i used a random vector y0, then i can recover the largest eigen vector

I want to recover a specific eigen vector with a specifc eigen value, not the largest eigen vector corresponding to largest eigen value

[image]

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but this looks like the [power method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).

Comment: Yes are you familiar with it?

Comment: Oh sorry, i am trying to recover some eigen vector with a specific eigen value

Comment: How may i do this, do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you already know the eigenvalue $\lambda$, then you can look for a vector in the nullspace of $A - \lambda I$.

Comment: @H When you say that you want an eigenvector for a "specific eigenvalue", does that mean that you know the exact eigenvalue associated with the eigenvector that you're looking for?

Comment: Yes the eigen value would be given, i need to find the eigen vector from it

Comment: Ok thank you angryavian for the hint, ill try it

Comment: Guys im very new to eigen vectors, i know the abstract process of eigen vectors but not any methods like power method. Currently i know Eigen decomposition, how to extract Eigen values from a Matrix, very few concepts. Can you point me to some more important concepts involving Eigen vectors like you mentioned power method

Comment: @HyperRelic A standard reference for numerical linear algebra is Trefethen and Bao. However, finding the eigenvector associated with a known eigenvalue is a process that is covered in practically every introductory linear algebra textbook, so it is very surprising that you know how to find the eigenvalues of a matrix without also knowing how to find the associated eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the comments: in this case, there is a known eigenvalue $\lambda$ for which you want the associated eigenvector(s). In that case, all you need to do is compute the null space of the matrix $A - \lambda I$ (where $I$ denotes the identity matrix).

The standard paper-and-pencil method to do this is row-reduction, but there exist methods that are more efficient for large matrices.